# What are the steps to schedule a scraper to input data on Google Sheets with Python, Heroku and GitHub?

Tags: python, heroku, web-scraping, gunicorn

What are the steps and the best tutorials for someone who wants to keep a Python scraper running with Heroku to input data in a sheet on Google Drive?

These are the steps that I did, but I'm not sure if something is missing because I still have trouble when running:

- Created a repository on GitHub, where I uploaded my scraper, a Procfile (web: gunicorn app:app), requirements file and deploy.yml.
- Added Heroku's API, email and apps name on my 'Actions secrets' on GitHub
- Created a project on Heroku and added Google Sheets credentials and ID
- Scheduled my script to run each 10 minutes on Heroku

What did I miss?

Comment: "What are the steps and the best tutorials for someone who wants to keep a Python scraper running with Heroku to input data in a sheet on Google Drive?"—please review what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow isn't here to replace search engines, documentation, or tutorials. And questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource are explicitly off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Now, what does "I still have trouble when running" mean? Please read [ask].